# Find proceses listening on the network outside of default package manager

Tags: beginner, bash, linux, networking

I have been tinkering with a script that should list things that are listening on the network, but are not part of the base packaging manager. Currently I have only done support for fedora and debian based systems.

Due to constraints on the system I am working on I have to support Bash 3.2 and above. This meant I got a bunch of complaints from shellcheck. Some of the things I think I did optimally

- How to properly read variables into arrays on older bash versions
- How to set a command `pkg` from the commandline argument `pkg` (for instance)
- Not sure how to avoid using `"$?"` in the last `if` as it complains if I push the entire function into the condition
- The last part using `lsof` is a bit of an hack, as I was unsure on how to extract the correct path without resorting to using the `PID`

Any feedback or improvements are more than welcome. I did run `shfmt` over the code, so it should be decently formatted.

Example output

[image]

```
#!/bin/bash

# finds processes listening in on the network outside outside of the default package manager

usage="usage $(basename "$0").sh [-h] [-f] [-a] [-w] [-v] [-p]

Lists packages listening on the network outside of the default package manager

where:
    -h,  --help              show this help text
    -f,  --whitelist-file    pick a file[s] containing whitelisted programs
    -a,  --list-all          display all processes listening on the network
    -w,  --whitelist         explicitly add whitelisted programs
    -v,  --view-whitelist    view the complete whitelist
    -p,  --package-manager   which package-manager to use (rpm, dkpg, ...)

output:
  COMMAND    PATH                PID    USER     FD   TYPE  DEVICE    SIZE/OFF  NODE  NAME
  mattermos  /app/main/mattermo  3351   361000   25u  IPv4  84625698  0t0       TCP   129.240...(ESTABLISHED)

examples:
    List all processes listening on the network
      usit_network_listeners --list-all 

    List only packages not maintained by the central package manager system
      usit_network_listeners --list-all 

    Whitelist some processes 
      usit_network_listeners --whitelist mattermos,systemd
      usit_network_listeners --whitelist 'mattermos systemd'

    Whitelist some processes using whitelist files
      usit_network_listeners -f /etc/uio/uio_listeners_whitelist_01.txt

    Multiple whitelist files is supported
      usit_network_listeners --whitelist foo.txt,bar.txt

environment variables:
  The following environment variables are available
  
    USIT_LISTENER_WHITELIST
    USIT_LISTENER_WHITELIST_FILES
  
  These form the base for the whitelist and whitelist files respectively. 
  Use a string with spaces or comma [,] as seperator for the values.
"

# Transform long options to short ones
for arg in "$@"; do
    shift
    case "$arg" in
    '--whitelist')        set -- "$@" '-w' ;;
    '--whitelist-file')   set -- "$@" '-f' ;;
    '--list-all')         set -- "$@" '-a' ;;
    '--view-whitelist')   set -- "$@" '-v' ;;
    '--package-manager')  set -- "$@" '-p' ;;
    '--help')             set -- "$@" '-h' ;;
    *)                    set -- "$@" "$arg" ;;
    esac
done

# The '//,/ ' allows us to input variables using , seperator as well as SPACE
read -ar whitelist <<<"${USIT_LISTENER_WHITELIST//,/ }"
read -ar whitelist_files <<<"${USIT_LISTENER_WHITELIST_FILES//,/ }"
list_all=false
view_whitelist=false
while getopts ":w:f:p:avh" flag; do
    case "${flag}" in
    h)
        echo "$usage"
        exit 0
        ;;
    a) list_all=true ;;
    v) view_whitelist=true ;;
    w) whitelist+=(${OPTARG//,/ }) ;;
    f) whitelist_files+=(${OPTARG//,/ }) ;;
    p) package_manager=${OPTARG} ;;
    \?)
        printf "illegal option: -%s\n" "$OPTARG" >&2
        echo "$usage" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done

# Some logic is needed to figure out which base package manager the system uses
dpkg_equivalents=("dpkg" "apt")
rpm_equivalents=("rpm" "yum" "dnf")
if [ -z "${package_manager}" ]; then
    if dpkg --version &>/dev/null; then
        package_manager="dpkg"
    elif rpm --version &>/dev/null; then
        package_manager="rpm"
    else
        echo "No supported package manager found! Try specifing one with -p --package-manager"
        exit 1
    fi
fi
if [[ ${dpkg_equivalents[*]} =~ ${package_manager} ]] && dpkg --version &>/dev/null; then
    package_manager="dpkg"
elif [[ ${rpm_equivalents[*]} =~ ${package_manager} ]] && rpm --version &>/dev/null; then
    package_manager="rpm"
else
    echo "ERROR: the package manager ${package_manager} is not supported on your system!"
    exit 1
fi

# The whitelist can also come from an array of files, add these to the global whitelist
while IFS= read -r whitelist_file; do
    if test -f "${whitelist_file}"; then
        readarray -t arr <"${whitelist_file}"
        whitelist=("${whitelist[@]}" "${arr[@]}")
    fi
done <<<"${whitelist_files[@]}"

# It could happen same file is whitelisted multiple times. We only keep unique values
whitelist=($(printf "%q\n" "${whitelist[@]}" | sort -u))

if [ "${view_whitelist}" = true ]; then
    if ((${#whitelist[@]})); then
        printf "%s\n" "${whitelist[@]}"
    fi
    exit
fi

# -i : This option filters only processes whith an IPv[46] address:
# -P : This option inhibits the conversion of port numbers to port names for network files.
# -n : This option inhibits the conversion of network numbers to host names for network files.
# -l : This option inhibits the conversion of user ID numbers to login names.
# +M : Enables the reporting of portmapper registrations for local TCP and UDP ports.
# The awk filters only unique PID's by  _[val] looks up val in the hash _(a regular variable).
# Tail is used to skip the header
listeners=$(
    lsof -Pnl +M -i |
        awk -F" " '!_[$1]++' |
        tail -n +2
)

# A bit cumbersome but this makes sure we define the correct package system only once
# Logic: If the command can not find $1 then output $2, we suppress any output as well
programname=""
if [ "${package_manager}" == "rpm" ]; then
    is_in_standard_repo() {
        rpm -qf "${1}" &>/dev/null
    }
elif [ "${package_manager}" == "dpkg" ]; then
    is_in_standard_repo() {
        dpkg -S "${1}" &>/dev/null
    }
else
    echo "The package manager ${package_manager} is not supported! Choose rpm (red hat) or dpkg (debian)"
    exit 1
fi

result=()
# Next step is extracting the paths from the PID's
while IFS= read -r line; do
    programname=$(echo "${line}" | awk '{print $1}')
    pid=$(echo "${line}" | awk '{print $2}')
    path=$(lsof -p "${pid}" 2>/dev/null | awk '/txt/ {print $9}')
    line=${line/$programname/$programname   $path}
    if [ "$list_all" = true ]; then
        result+=("${line}")
    else
        is_in_standard_repo "$path"
        # If path is in standard repo AND not in whitelist print the line
        if [ "$?" -gt 0 ] && [[ ! ${whitelist[*]} =~ ${programname} ]]; then
            result+=("${line}")
        fi
    fi
done <<<"$listeners"

# Pretty format the output
printf '%s\n' "${result[@]}" | column -t
```

Comment: Are you expecting this to run as a privileged (i.e. `root`) or as an unprivileged user?

Comment: @TobySpeight This will be running as root =)

Comment: In that case, you have full access to `/proc`, which might turn out more efficient than invoking `lsof` in that loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, pretty nice script! (I think you could drop the [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner) tag ;-)

#### Dodgy transformation of long options

When transforming the long options to short ones,
I find it a bit dodgy to use `set -- "$@" ...`.
It feels like a dirty hack to iterate over the arguments \$n\$ to \$2n\$ times,
and doing that in a `for arg in "$@"` loop with a `shift`,
replacing the list being iterated on.

It would be cleaner to collect the transformed args in another array,
and then replace `$@` with the items of that array:

```
args=()

for arg; do
    case $arg in
    '--whitelist')        args+=(-w) ;;
    '--whitelist-file')   args+=(-f) ;;
    '--list-all')         args+=(-a) ;;
    '--view-whitelist')   args+=(-v) ;;
    '--package-manager')  args+=(-p) ;;
    '--help')             args+=(-h) ;;
    *)                    args+=("$arg") ;;
    esac
done

set -- "${args[@]}"
```

This is cleaner because the underlying argument list of the loop is not replaced in the middle of iterations,
and `$@` is not re-copied repeatedly,
but replaced once at the end.

#### Always double-quote variables on the command line

I guess you don't support spaces in parameters of `-w`, because that would not work here:

> ```
> w) whitelist+=(${OPTARG//,/ }) ;;
> ```

When appending the contents of a variable to an array, the correct form is:

```
arr+=("$somevar")
```

A clean solution would be:

```
IFS=, read -ra parts <<< "$OPTARG"
whitelist+=("${parts[@]}")
;;
```

#### Review the order or operations

A sequence of operations should be in order such that:

- Avoid unnecessary work
- Related operations are close together

Consider this part from the posted code, with some details hidden:

> ```
> if [[ ${dpkg_equivalents[*]} =~ ${package_manager} ]] && ...; then
>     package_manager="dpkg"
> elif ...
>     package_manager="rpm"
> else
>     exit 1
> fi
>
> while IFS= read -r whitelist_file; do
>     # ...
>
> listeners=$(lsof ...)
>
> programname=""
> if [ "${package_manager}" == "rpm" ]; then
>     # ...
> else
>     exit 1
> fi
>
> while IFS= read -r line; do
>     programname=...
>     # ...
> done <<<"$listeners"
> ```

At first I though that the output of `lsof` might not be used,
since there's a conditional exit after it,
independently.

Then I noticed that `package_manager` was already validated earlier in the code.
Why is it checked again?
The `else` branch will never be taken.
If the code pieces related to `package_manager` were closer to each other,
it would be easier to see that something is off.

Also notice that before the validation of `package_manager`,
there is also an auto-detection mechanism.
The validation should not be necessary when the value was set by auto-detection.

The `lsof` should be called right before the loop that uses its result.
Also, instead of storing its output in a variable,
you could pipe that directly into the `while` loop.

Finally, notice that `programname` is initialized too early.
It appears right before an `if-else`,
and I'm confused to not find any references to it in that `if-else`.
It is updated in a `while` loop later,
so it would be good to move the initialization to right in front of that loop.

#### Don't define functions in conditional blocks

It's cool that you can define functions in an `if-else` in Bash,
but I think it's unusual.
I would use a variable to store the function name, something like this:

```
is_in_rpm_repo() {
    rpm -qf "${1}" &>/dev/null
}

is_in_standard_repo=
if [ "${package_manager}" == "rpm" ]; then
    is_in_standard_repo=is_in_rpm_repo
    # ...


if "$is_in_standard_repo" "$path"; then
    # ...
```

#### Use consistent style

Most conditions use `[ ... ]`, but there is one instance of `test`.
I recommend `[ ... ]` consistently.

Many places use `<<< "..."` here-strings, but there are a few `echo | ...`.
I recommend here-strings consistently.

Some of the error messages are correctly printed to `stderr`.
Some are printed to `stdout`.
And since it's a bit annoying to type `>&2` and `exit 1` repeatedly,
I usually define a `fatal` helper function:

```
fatal() {
    echo "fatal: $*" >&2
    exit 1
}
```

#### Use a here-document instead of a multiline double-quoted string

With a multiline double-quoted string as in the definition of the `usage` variable,
I would be afraid that someday somebody will accidentally add a double-quote somewhere in the content and forgets to escape it properly,
breaking the script.
I would sleep better if the long string was defined as a here-document, which is harder to mess up.

```
read -r usage <<< EOF
# ...
EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

This chain looks like a candidate for `case`…`in`:

> ```
> if [ "${package_manager}" == "rpm" ]; then
> ⋮ 
> elif [ "${package_manager}" == "dpkg" ]; then
> ⋮ 
> else
> ⋮ 
> fi
> ```

Also, the error message in the `else` block should go to the error stream, not the output stream.  That appears to be an oversight, given that other error messages go to the right place.

---

If `$package_manager` can only have one of a few values, we could name our function alternatives thus:

```
is_in_standard_repo_rmp() {
    rpm -qf "${1}" &>/dev/null
}
is_in_standard_repo_dpkg() {
    dpkg -S "${1}" &>/dev/null
}
```

and then invoke `is_in_standard_repo_$package_manager` to get the correct one.  This is particularly useful once you accumulate additional per-platform functions and/or more platforms.

---

Why not sort/uniq the whitelist *before* assigning to array?  I.e. replace this:

> ```
> while IFS= read -r whitelist_file; do
>         readarray -t arr <"${whitelist_file}"
>         whitelist=("${whitelist[@]}" "${arr[@]}")
> done <<<"${whitelist_files[@]}"
>
> whitelist=($(printf "%q\n" "${whitelist[@]}" | sort -u))
> ```

with:

```
readarray -t whitelist < <(sort -u "${whitelist_files[@]}")
```

---

The comment here is missing a negative if it's to agree with the code:

> ```
>     is_in_standard_repo "$path"
>     # If path is in standard repo AND not in whitelist print the line
>     if [ "$?" -gt 0 ] && [[ ! ${whitelist[*]} =~ ${programname} ]]
> ```

`if [ "$?" -gt 0 ]` is a well-known anti-pattern.  Just use the command's exit status directly rather than examining `$?`:

```
if ! is_in_standard_repo "$path" && …
```

---

We can simplify here:

> ```
> if [ "$list_all" = true ]; then
> ```

Given that we know the variable must be either `true` or `false`, we can just execute it:

```
if "$list_all"
```

Comment: Great answer! So many useful tips and tricks. Unfortunately the `readarray` did not work as I need to support bash 3.2+

Comment: I wasn't quite sure how that fitted in with the version requirements, but glad the rest was helpful.